# Javascript prompt - Data hides in ie

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-7, internet-explorer-6

**Button**

```
<input type="button" id="button" value="Prompt">
```

**Javascript**

```
<script>
$("#button").click(function(){
var check = prompt("this is a sample this is a sample this is a sample this is a sample this is a sample this is a sample this is a sample this is a sample this is a sample this is a sample this is a sample this is a sample this is a sample this is a sample this is a sample this is a sample this is a sample this is a sample this is a sample this is a sample this is a sample this is a sample this is a sample this is a sample this is a sample this is a sample this is a sample this is a sample this is a sample this is a sample this is a sample this is a sample this is a sample this is a sample this is a sample this is a sample this is a sample this is a sample this is a sample this is a sample this is a sample this is a sample this is a sample this is a sample this is a sample this is a sample this is a sample this is a sample this is a sample this is a sample this is a sample this is a sample this is a sample this is a sample this is a sample this is a sample this is a sample this is a sample this is a sample this is a sample this is a sample this is a sample this is a sample this is a sample this is a sample this is a sample this is a sample this is a sample this is a sample this is a sample this is a sample this is a sample this is a sample this is a sample this is a sample this is a sample this is a sample this is a sample" , "");
alert(check);
});
</script>
```

While giving a words in prompt. internet explorer display only one line and hide the other sentence. I need to display a lengthy paragraph in promopt in ie.

Help me to solve this...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/G3MsT/2/ shows 2 lines in my.. But maybe you should consider a modal box if you want to display a lengthy messeage? I don't think you can control the alert box since it's generated by the browser.

Comment: works fine in IE8 for me

Comment: @Marco Your fiddle is using an alert box, the OP requested a prompt. In IE, the alert and confirm boxes allow a lot more text than a prompt box does.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan woops.. sorry, corrected my link. Maybe he should use an alert box for the messeage, and then use the prompt afterwards? Still a model JS soloution would be the best :)

Comment: @Marco That's another solution, but not very user friendly. Definately agree that a modal is the way forward here :)

Comment: Might not be a best solution from UX perspective, but there's also window.showModalDialog() https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.showModalDialog

Comment: This problem is not related to jQuery or HTML, removed the irrelevant tags.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way in IE to extend the length of text in a prompt box - it will simply be truncated after 2 lines.

The only workable alternative is to create a modal popup with your own text input inside.

IMO, this is a better solution anyway.

Answer (score 0):

IE's prompt can not be changed from javascript. My suggestion use jQuery.UI. [sample](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal-confirmation)

**Sample:**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>jQuery UI Dialog Sample</title>
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.4/themes/start/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="dialog" style="display:none">
this is a sample this is a sample this is a sample this is a sample this is a sample this is a sample this is a sample this is a sample this is a sample this is a sample this is a sample this is a sample this is a sample this is a sample this is a sample this is a sample this is a sample this is a sample this is a sample this is a sample this is a sample this is a sample this is a sample this is a sample this is a sample this is a sample this is a sample this is a sample this is a sample this is a sample this is a sample this is a sample this is a sample this is a sample this is a sample this is a sample this is a sample this is a sample this is a sample this is a sample this is a sample this is a sample this is a sample this is a sample this is a sample this is a sample this is a sample this is a sample this is a sample this is a sample this is a sample this is a sample this is a sample this is a sample this is a sample this is a sample this is a sample this is a sample this is a sample this is a sample this is a sample this is a sample this is a sample this is a sample this is a sample this is a sample this is a sample this is a sample this is a sample this is a sample this is a sample this is a sample this is a sample this is a sample this is a sample this is a sample this is a sample this is a sample<br />
<input type="text" id="Check" name="check" value="" />
</div>
<input type="button" id="button" value="Prompt" />
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#button").click(function(){
    var check ="";
    $("#dialog").dialog({
        /* title: "test", */
        modal: true,
        width: 640,
        buttons: { 
            "Ok": function() { 
                check = $('#Check:input').val();
                $(this).dialog("close");
                alert(check);
            }, 
            "Cancel": function() {
                $('#Check:input').val("");
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }
    });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```